# How to create watermark with imagemagick

Tags: php, imagemagick, overlay, watermark

I'm trying to create a watermark with ImageMagick however, the guides on layering are pretty daunting.  Basically I'll have one base image say "base.jgp" and an overlay image say "overlay.jpg".  Overlay.jpg would be smaller than base.jpg. Which exec command would I run to place overlay centered on top of base.jpg?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
shell_exec("composite -gravity center ./images/watermark_horizontal.png {$this->path} {$this->path}");
```

Here we go

Comment: how to use it in php?

Answer (score 2):

Check out [ImageMagick examples](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/), especially the [Compositing Images](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compose/) chapter. It has a number of ready-made real-world examples.

Comment: This is the daunting guide that I was referring to.

Comment: @ThinkingInBits but it contains an example showing how to center an image on top of the other, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

```
$image = new Imagick();
$image->readImage("image.jpg");

// Open the watermark
$watermark = new Imagick();
$watermark->readImage("watermark.png");

// Overlay the watermark on the original image
$image->compositeImage($watermark, imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, 0, 0);

// send the result to the browser
header("Content-Type: image/" . $image->getImageFormat());
```

Comment: Some narrative would be very nice here. Please explain what you did.